# Dropdown with Icon in Salesforce Lightning Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Would like to ask if it is possible to create a dropdown with icons (similar to the image below) in salesforce lightning component?

[image]

Comment: Jaymz Azaña, how did you do it please? I have same requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these:

1. `menu` slds styles: [Menus - Icon on the Left](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#Icon-on-the-Left)
2. `lightning:buttonMenu` component: [lightning:buttonMenu](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleButtonMenuSingleIcon)